# Forward all exim outgoing mails to mailhog

Tags: smtp, exim

I  am trying to relay all outgoing mails that are sended from any kind of software via my smtp exim4 on port 25, to mailhog on port 1025 on same machine. Is this possible?

I have tried:

```
 begin routers

 driver=manualrouter
 transport = mailhog
 route_list = * 127.0.0.1::1025
 domains = *

 mailhog:
 driver = smtp
```

and much more combinations but it is unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, but configuration parameters must be applied exactly as they are in the manual: even a minor typo leads to a whole different outcome, and you seem to have more than one here.

You have probably followed a tutorial like [Exim with remote SMTP server](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Exim_with_remote_SMTP_server) from ArchLinux Wiki.

> At the end of the Routers Configuration section add:
>
> ```
> passonto_isp:
>   driver = manualroute
>   domains = !+local_domains
>   transport = remote_smtp
>   route_list = * smtp.myisp.com        # change to the desired smtp server
> ```
>
> Make sure that in Transports Configuration it says (uncommented):
>
> ```
> remote_smtp:
>   driver = smtp
> ```

**Ok, so what's different?**

- The very first line, `passonto_isp:`. You must specify the router before giving its settings.
- While the white space in the [common option syntax](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_exim_run_time_configuration_file.html#SECTcos) is optional, the driver name of [the manualroute router](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_manualroute_router.html) is exactly `manualroute`, i.e. without the `r` in the ending, as you have.
- Are you really sure you also want this to be applied on local domains? `*` vs. `!+local_domains`, where `!` makes it a negation of `+local_domains`, i.e. everything but local domains.
- Every cloud has a silver lining: you have avoided a common error: in `route_list` you haven't messed with the [hosts list separator](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_manualroute_router.html#SECID12) `:`, but used `::` to separate the port from the hostname.

  > Because colon is the default separator for the list of hosts, either
  >   the colon that specifies a port must be doubled, or the list separator
  >   must be changed. The following two examples have the same effect:
  >
  > ```
  > route_list = * "host1.tld::1225 : host2.tld::1226" 
  > route_list = * "<+ host1.tld:1225 + host2.tld:1226"
  > ```
- You have specified `transport = mailhog`. Your `mailhog:` should be in `transports` section.

**Resulting config:**

```
begin routers

passonto_mailhog:
  driver = manualroute
  domains = !+local_domains
  transport = mailhog
  route_list = * 127.0.0.1::1025
```

---

```
begin transports

mailhog:
  driver = smtp
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I am neither getting mail in mailhog, nether it is sent.

Comment: And also, i am not receiving any mails now, but i want to receive mails properly, only to catch all outgoing mails in mailhog.

Comment: Then you probably have something else wrong with the configuration. Do the logs tell you anything?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/demil/c39f533143f3cef2ad2ea7c31b7df36a

Comment: That configuration seems ok now, but what happens, if you send mail to this server? See your logs for everything related to a single delivery of one message.

Comment: Here is log, and it is same for sending and recieving. It seems that it handles incoming mails same as outgoing and it sys that uses passonto_mailhog, but there isnt anything there.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/demil/c39f533143f3cef2ad2ea7c31b7df36a

Comment: And if i send message to my self i am receiving? But i am not receiving messages from outside nor catching sended messages from inside, nor catching that message that i sended from inside? I don understand anything :)